# Dynamic table control creation?

Tags: dynamic, abap, dynpro

I have a task to create tableview on a GUI screen dynamically. The control must be created dynamically fo different table types, because we need to maintain different tables. I mean I need SM30 looking table maintainance screen.

Is it possible in ABAP to create tableview dynamically? Or is it possible within ALV grids only?

Comment: No doubt that the ALV Grid Control is more powerful than the old Dynpro **Table Control** technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any alternative table view for SAP GUI. You need to use ALV to show multiple lines same time.

You can [create ALV dynamically](https://answers.sap.com/questions/7782340/dynamic-table-in-alv.html).

Answer (score 2):

As a very slim trick use `STC1_FULLSCREEN_TABLE_CONTROL`. It makes table control  just in time

```
CALL FUNCTION 'STC1_FULLSCREEN_TABLE_CONTROL'
  EXPORTING
    header                  = 'MyTab'
    tabname                 = 'MARA'
    no_button               = 'X'
  TABLES
    table                   = lt_mara
  EXCEPTIONS
    no_more_tables          = 1
    too_many_fields         = 2
    nametab_not_valid       = 3
    handle_not_valid        = 4
    OTHERS                  = 5
.
```

However, I agree with the rest of commenters that ALV grid will be much better for this case.